# Why does my remote attribute not working on register method and view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When I move the focus from the `UserName` textbox the page does not render the error message, nor does it allow a page submit.

```
// POST: /Account/Register
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.UserName};
        user.UserName = model.UserName;
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            await this.UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, model.Name);
            return RedirectToAction("Index","User");
        }
        AddErrors(result);
    }
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult doesUserNameExist(string UserName)
{
    var user = Membership.GetUser(UserName);
    return Json(user == null);
}
```

Inside my AccountViewModel:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    [Remote("doesUserNameExist", "Account", ErrorMessage = "{0} User name already exists. Please enter a different user name.")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

}
```

Inside my bundle config:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

Comment: If your controller is decorated with`[Authorize]`, then you will also need `[AllowAnonymous]` on the `doesUserNameExist()` method. You also need to specify `HttpMethod = "Post"` in the `RemoteAttribute` (or remove `[HttpPost]` from the method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `[HttpPost]` before `doesUserNameExist` and edit `doesUserNameExist` like this:

```
public JsonResult doesUserNameExist(string username)
{
    var user = Membership.GetUserByName(username.Trim());
    return user == null ? 
        Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet) : 
        Json(string.Format("{0} is not available.", username),
            JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```